# Taiga Bitbucket Integration

Tags: bitbucket, webhooks

I was trying to integrate Bitbucket in the taiga. But I'm not able to figure it out how to do it. I went through support section also but no result.

I'm new to this so please can anyone help me how to integrate bitbucket in Taiga.

If there is any video or blog please share the link it will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this link](https://taiga.io/support/bitbucket-integration/) from the Taiga documentation. It goes through the process of integrating information from your bitbucket repository using bitbucket webhooks.